# jQuery .toggle change z-index after animation instead of display: none

Tags: jquery, toggle, z-index, slidetoggle

Is there any way i can change the toggle function or any of it's other functions (fadein, fadeout, slidetoggle etc) to make it instead of changing the display to none, it keeps display as block but makes the z-index to -9999 to achieve the same effect? I need this because inside my div, i have scrollable content, and when the div is recalled, the scroll starts back at the top instead of where the user was last at. Or alternatively, is there a way to on postback to immediately scroll to a class with .imgactive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this snippet will give you some ide how to implment that function:

```
$.fn.toggleZindex= function() {
  var $this  = $(this);
    if($this.css("z-index")=="-99999"){
        $this.css("z-index","99999")
    }else{
        $this.css("z-index","-99999")
    }


  return this;
};
```

And a mini demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4NQXa/

Comment: Thanks man, however now is it possible i could animate a slide function in to it?

Comment: animate a slide function? What do you mean?

Comment: I'd like to achieve an animation like the one on slideIn and slideOut or slideToggle. However, i can't use slideToggles because otherwise it changes the display from block to none, is there a way i can maybe make it animate to have a top of say -500 px so it recreates the slide but instead of display it as none, it still displays as a block but outside of the actual container?

Comment: This sounds like a diffrent question for me. You should accept one of the answers if they satisfied your orginal question and ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

yes absolutely, you can use toggle to do pretty much anything you would like
If you just use toggle like

```
$(this).toggle();
```

i believe it will only do a show/hide, but if you use it as an actual event handler it will do what ever you want it to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("td").toggle(function(){
     $(this).css("z-index","99999");
   },
   function(){
      $(this).css("z-index","-99999");
   });
});
```

basically it just switches between those two "function()"'s between ever click on a "td"